# Using 2 images in array to output multiple on canvas - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I am currently stuck on an output which i am trying to create.

My aim is to use two particular images which then will be used to create multiple copies on a canvas whilst they are moving from the top of the canvas to the bottom - continuously .

I have looked into arrays but have not found how the images can be 'duplicated' for e.g. if i were to use an array to store these 2 images, how would i output 100 of these onto the canvas without manually writing 100 lines

Any help would be appreciated

CJ

Comment: Something like `for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) canvas.drawImage(image, 0, i);`? Can you give us some code / your attempted implementaion?

Comment: I have no current code as i do not know where to begin. After looking at the examples online the code is very complex, i was wondering if there is a simplified version of making for e.g. 10 copies of 2 images on a canvas